# R monthly plot with GGPlot2 in RMarkdown

Tags: r, csv, plot, ggplot2

I have a CSV file with the following data:

RegistrationDate;User_Id;Items

RegistrationDate has format like '22.05.2014 14:25'

1. Is there any easy way to connect CSV data to R markdown script? All of examples I've seen use random generated data, that looks too bad for reproducible research.
2. I need to create 2 plots with ggplot2:

   - a plot of users count per month.
   - a plot of items collected per month

I've checked a lot of graphs looks close to this one, but didn't find any right version. Looks like I don't understand something about R plotting :(.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say "connect" CSV data to R markdown sript?
You mean reading them?

```
data <- read.csv("directory/name.csv", sep=";")
```

Or you mean adding `somewhere` a specific relation, telling that this data is related to this analysis? If the second, you can check the [archivist](https://github.com/pbiecek/archivist) package, stored on GitHub, that possess a set of tools for datasets and figures archivisation. There is a information how to install that package.

In question 2, you will need an extra column that specifies the month.

Comment: I've loaded this csv to list with 3 columns. But when I convert it like this:

   my_users$date <- as.Date(my_users[,"DateTime"], format="%m-%y")

I get date column filled with <NA>. What do I do wrong?